# How to understand the "otherwise" in this sentense?

Tags: sentence-meaning

The sentence is:
    This weaknesses negated his otherwise progressive attitude towards the staff.

I feel hard to understand the meaning of "otherwise progressive attitude".
How to transfer this sentence into a simple one?

Comment: *Weakness*, you mean.

Answer (score 1):

*Otherwise* is an adverb meaning *In other respects; apart from that* (Oxforddictionaries.com)

> an otherwise totally black cat with a single white whisker

Your sentence means

> His attitude towards the staff was positive in the whole, except for this weakness.